# how to make an image to fill 2 columns in an image grid

Tags: html, css

I am new to writing html and css code. I tried to make an image gallery with three column using CSS FlexBox

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img src="sea.jpg">
      <img src="guns.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="cars.jpg">
      <img src="gg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="games.jpg">
      <img src="games.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding:10,10px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The result of the code above is a normal three column image grid with pictures filled in each column. Is there any way to make the first image in the first row, first column span to first row, second column?

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox with this? so it's clearer what you need

Comment: @poca sorry I only wrote this on a code editor and I don't have much knowledge on React... Here is a picture of what I want to achieve.    https://imgur.com/dE1ra7z      so I want to create a three column image grid; but sometimes certain image will span two columns. Sorry about the picture's quality.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good for someone new to HTML/CSS! But you probably have never heard about CSS grid.

Flexbox is great for one-column or one-row organization, but lacks in multi-column/multi-row organization. That's where css grid comes in.

To make an object a grid, do

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
}
```

Then, we need to specify the amount of columns and rows. We can use the `grid-template-rows` and `grid-template-columns properties for this. For every extra value you add, you add another row/column. For example,` grid-template-columns: 20px 20px;' would generate two columns, each 20px wide. If you specify the width and height of the container, then you can set the value to auto (e.g. `grid-template-columns: auto auto;`, which creates two columns that are equal size and as wide as possible while still staying in the boundaries of the grid. The same applies for `grid-template-rows`. So lets assume, for now, you want a 100px by 100px 3x3 grid.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

Great! Now we need to specify where we want the grid items to go. We use the `grid-row` and `grid-column` properties for this. Let's take a look at what it looks like.

```css
#image-one {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
}
```

So what do those numbers mean?

Well, when we created the 3x3 grid, the actually created 4 vertical lines and 4 horizontal lines. Draw out a 3x3 grid with borders if you are confused, you'll see 4 horizontal lines and 4 vertical lines.

So, the code is saying that the first image should be between horizontal grid lines 1 and 2 and between vertical grid lines 1 and 2. Going back to your drawing, this is the first box!

Now you can do this for every single image. Here's the second image:

```css
#image-two {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

This puts the image on the first row, second column. Remember, draw a picture if you get stuck! This is hard because we are describing visual instructions with text, so using a drawing to help translate is super helpful.

Also, the images do not have to take up a 1 by 1 space on the grid. For example, you could make a 2x2 image that starts at the very first box by doing...

```css
#test-image {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

...which puts the image between horizontal grid lines 1 and 3 and vertical grid lines 1 and 3, a.k.a. making a 2x2 box! Again, draw a diagram if you're confused.

Also, for further reading and helpful diagrams, check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/. They do a better job explaining than I ever could. Also, they have an excellent tutorial/review/documentation on flex-box, if you're curious: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: Thank you for the help! But the image does not fill the whole grid if I do `img1{grid-row:1/2; grid-column 1/3;}` Is there a way to fill the whole grid?

Comment: you might want to try to use the image as a background image instead of an image so that it grows with the container

Comment: or take a look at flex grow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow

Comment: You have a 3x3 grid right? So in a 3 by 3 grid there are 4 grid lines and 4 grid columns. So you want it to go from the first grid line to the 4th grid line, and from the first grid column to the 4th grid column, so you could do `img1{grid-row:1/4; grid-column:1/4;}`